# Color xticks to match color of scatter plot points

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, scatter-plot, xticks

Here is my plot:
[image]

generated from the python code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
n = 70
x = [f'{i}{val}' for i,val in enumerate(np.arange(n)[::-1])]
y = np.random.randint(50, 100, n)
scatter_colors = np.random.rand(n)

plt.scatter(x, y, c=scatter_colors)
plt.xticks(rotation=90, ha='right')
plt.show()
```

Any ideas on how to make the ticks labels have the same color as the plotted points?
Adding `c=scatter_colors` or `color=scatter_colors` to the `plt.xticks(rotation=90, ha='right')` throws a value error.
The data is gibberish and just minimum to reproduce what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach (rewritten using the object-oriented interface) using [`Axes.get_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticklabels.html) and [`Text.set_color`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_color):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
n = 70
x = [f'{i}{val}' for i,val in enumerate(np.arange(n)[::-1])]
y = np.random.randint(50, 100, n)

scatter_colors = np.random.rand(n)
viridis = plt.get_cmap('viridis')

ax.scatter(x, y, c=scatter_colors)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(n), x, ha='right', rotation=90)

for color, label in zip(scatter_colors, ax.get_xticklabels()):
    label.set_color(viridis(color))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Also doable with the pyplot interface:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
n = 70
x = [f'{i}{val}' for i,val in enumerate(np.arange(n)[::-1])]
y = np.random.randint(50, 100, n)

scatter_colors = np.random.rand(n)
viridis = plt.get_cmap('viridis')

plt.scatter(x, y, c=scatter_colors)
plt.xticks(rotation=90, ha='right')

for color, label in zip(scatter_colors, plt.xticks()[1]):
    label.set_color(viridis(color))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. Can it be done directly with `plt` without involving `ax`?

Comment: @Toonia see the edit. Short answer, yes, although that is not the recommended approach.

Comment: Great. Why is it not recommended?

Comment: This [post](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/) has a thorough explanation of both interfaces and why the object-oriented interface is recommended.